# 'yeoman' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: angularjs, yeoman

I am trying to learn angularjs, in between i came across yeoman, So i tried installing yeoman, 
I refered : http://decodize.com/css/installing-yeoman-front-end-development-stack-windows/
at the line "There are 2 method to install Yeoman.", i followed "a." And installed by

Command prompt: 
D:\Angular_Work_Space>npm install yeoman

after downloading all the packages, i could able to see the node_modules/ folder in 'Angular_Work_Space',

So after this, i tried, 
D:\Angular_Work_Space>yeoman init

got error: 
**'yeoman' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**

please tell me what i have missed on what else to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the npm-package `yeoman`is deprecated and shouldnt be used anymore. Your Article is from 2012, so thats pretty old in the world of the rapidly developing JS-World. ;)

What you need is the package `yo`.

Further, you dont install yeoman locally, but globally like this:
`npm install -g yo`

To initialize a project, you probabyl will also need a generator. But i suggest you just crawl yourself through the yeoman-documentation [here](http://yeoman.io/gettingstarted.html)

Comment: thanks, i think it worked, 
D:\Angular_Work_Space>yo
[?] What would you like to do? (Use arrow keys)
> Run the Angular generator (0.7.1)
  Run the Webapp generator (0.4.7) Update Available! (0.4.8)
  Run the Karma generator (0.6.0) Update Available! (0.7.0)
  Run the Mocha generator (0.1.3)
  Update your generators
  Install a generator
  Find some help
  Get me out of here!.
Have one doubt, GLOBALLY (-g) means, where it would have installed?

Comment: There is two modes how you can install a package in npm:
INSIDE a Project, meaning its only available for that one specific project, or globally with `-g`, what makes it available for ALL Projects OR (like in this case) adds a CLI-Tool that can be used from  anywhere.